# Is there a web service engine able to wrap queries in a (SOAP) web service?

Tags: web-services, wrapper, rdbms

We have a very heterogeneus it environment, made of a main RDBMS (informix) and many aother RDBMSs (postgres, MS Sql, MySql...) due to several independent products acquired over time.
We need to **read** (just read) data from all these heterogeneus RDBMSs from within our main environment and we want to do it with web services (very likely SOAP ones) because of future rise of internal mobile applications.
I would like to set up (or write) a web services server that acts as a "wrapper" for all different databases, and it should more or less this way:
a) the tipical request should specify host, database and selection query and the typical response would be a recordset in xml form, like this for example:

```
<recordset>
    <row>
        <field1>content of field 1</field1>
        <field2>content of field 2</field2>
        ...
    </row>
</recordset>
```

b) It will run inside a "friendly" environment, queries wll be written just by IT dep. programmers, and will NEVER be accessibe from outside; this way security issues should be satisfied

My question is: before reinventing the wheel, is there something ready-made or similar in the open source community? 
The product should allow general queries and should not force to write a web mehod for each query...
I was not able to find such a product; Oracle seem to have something similar as a feature but Oracle is one of the few RDBMSs we currently do not have and this feature seems to expose just Oracle RDBMS as a web service, not any in the local network

Thank you in advance